# MySQL error 1593 on replication between 5.5 on WIndows and 5.6 on CentOS 7

Tags: mysql, replication

I'm setting up replication between the live server (running Windows 2008 R2 and MySQL 5.5.19) and a dedicated replication server (running CentOS 7 and MySQL 5.6.30). The CentOS box does have MySQL not MariaDB.

In the master my.ini, I've set:

```
server-id=131025185082
```

In the slave my.cnf, I've set:

```
server-id=192168001182
```

The server is generating a mysql-bin and I've configured the slave to connect. But; I'm getting a 1593 error:

```
Fatal error: The slave I/O thread stops because master and slave have  equal MySQL server ids; these ids must be different for replication to work (or the --replicate-same-server-id option must be used on slave but this does not always make sense; please check the manual before using it). The log position given is the start point from SHOW MASTER STATUS on the master.
```

When I do:

```
show variables like 'server_id';
```

on both machines, they both come back with:

```
+---------------+------------+
| Variable_name | Value      |
+---------------+------------+
| server_id     | 4294967295 |
+---------------+------------+
```

Can anyone suggest what's gone wrong here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If both the servers showing same server-id, you can set this to some other value and check again.

**On Master:**

```
server-id = 1
```

**On Slave:**

```
server-id = 2
```

Make sure that, while giving `change master` settings, give the host name as ip address of the master server. This should work, check again and see if the same issue exists. I hope this will help you.

Comment: I've changed the slave server-id & it worked. What was wrong with 192168001182? Thanks

Comment: The highest server id allowed is 4294967295 (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/replication-options.html#option_mysqld_server-id), just a little under 4.3 billion. Your number is over 192 billion. Way too big !!!